# Bootstrap nav bar dropdown submenu doens't work on mobile with single tap, it needs a prolonged tap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Well the title is self explanatory, check this out; http://testing.mkitra.com/4.2/
in the nav bar, the third link is a dropdown which has a submenu. On PC it works fine, it opens when the mouse hovers over it. Now try it on mobile environment. When you click it, the dropdown just closes, you need a prolonged tap to open the submenu. WHY?? Any recommendations?
 Thanks guys

Comment: it also doesn't work on pc. you hover that's why it feels like it works. try to click on dropdown-sub it will hide. in mobile there is no hover. it clicks that's why hides.

Comment: Yeah, true, even bigger problem than I thought then!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because in class **dropdown** of **bootstrap** it uses :hover. You should change it to use **jquery hide&show** and use **jquery-mobile** for making dropdown in mobile when clicked.
View link [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.1/selectmenu/)

Hope this will help!

Comment: Wow, this is so easy... Thanks @PeterSmith! One more question, how do I position the submenu on the right like my failed example?